# puppet module for nagios

Tags: puppet, nagios

I am trying to install nagios monitoring for my aws infrastructure.Can someone guide me a puppet module to be used for automating this requirement ?

I have some basic doubts , bear with me if they are so silly as I am still learning puppet.

1) How can I define my custom service checks in puppet module ?

2) What is the best way to populate my hosts detail via puppet>

Comment: I am trying to automate the nagios install and configure all my nodes via nagios

Comment: puppet with puppetdb en exported resources.

Comment: I am using puppetdb  with exported resources for my testing.Probably I can fix the issue by this approach.

Comment: with puppet you have native resource nagios_host,nagios_command,nagios_service and using this resource and some script in combination with puppet + exported resources

Comment: @c4f4t0r ,thanks for the suggestion,  I am looking  forward to that direction and trying to explore more .